# Regex add space in string if the word is longer than 4 characters and have numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to create a regex with 2 condition:

- if word length more than 4 character
- And if the word contains numbers

I need to add spaces

So like: `iph12` return `iph12`, but `iphone12` return `iphone 12`

I wrote regex

`.replace(/\d+/gi, ' $& ').trim()`

and this function return in anyway string like `iphone 12`. I tried to use function

`.replace(/(?=[A-Z]+\d|\d+[A-Z])[A-Z\d]{,4}/i, ' $& ').trim()`

but without second argument in `{,4}` it's not working. So is this possible?

Comment: *more than 4 characters* would be ```{4,}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
text.replace(/\b([a-zA-Z]{4,})(\d+)\b/g, '$1 $2')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sP2jK4/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `([a-zA-Z]{4,})` - Group 1: four or more ASCII letters
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\b` - word boundary

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['iphone12', 'iph12'];
const regex = /\b([a-zA-Z]{4,})(\d+)\b/g;
for (const text of texts) {
    console.log(text, '=>', text.replace(regex, '$1 $2'));
}
```

Output:

```
iphone12 => iphone 12
iph12 => iph12
```